# Playframework ram size production mode on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, playframework, playframework-2.0

I run an playframework application in a docker container on AWS EC2. Container config has 3000MB RAM.

But how can I set the application to run with 3000GB ram?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at JVM xms, xmx params

Comment: Yes I know locally I runt it like this: `sbt "run -Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf" -Xms2048M -Xmx4048M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` but where can I pass these parameter on aws?